# Filter on the uniquifier column in a non-unique clustered index

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, unique, clustered-index

I have a table with a non-unique clustered index. I want to move these records to a table with a unique clustered index (I don't care which single record I get out of the table). I can do this via a GROUP BY, but I suspect it could be faster to select off of the hidden uniquifier column.

I have found [some examples](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2082/understanding-and-examining-the-uniquifier-in-sql-server/) of how to access the value of the uniquifier column, but none that show how it might be uses in a query, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM NonUniqueClusteredIndexTable
WHERE uniquifier = 0
```

Any ideas how to access this value, or otherwise how to quickly de-duplicate such a table?

Comment: I think it is only in the index so it is not accessible through a `SELECT`.

Comment: Use `ROW_NUMBER` - you'll get your "uniquifier" if you think you need it for whatever purpose.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I'm going the `ROW_NUMBER()` path now, but figured if SQL Server had already done this work and included it in an index, it might be faster.